# Android Studio AddValueEventListener doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make recyclerview by data from firebase. My firebase database structure looks like below.

---

### [image]

However, my code failed to data into recyclerview. and I spent lots of times where the problem is. and it looks like addValueEventListenr issue. I dont know why but this listener doesnt proceed.

**Adapter class**

```
public class SymbolAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SymbolAdapter.SymbolHolder>{

  ArrayList<Symbol> symbol_list;
    public SymbolAdapter(ArrayList<Symbol> symbol_list){
        this.symbol_list = symbol_list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SymbolHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_item, parent, false);
        return new SymbolHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SymbolHolder holder, int position) {
        Symbol symbol = symbol_list.get(position);
        holder.symbol.setText(symbol.getSymbol());
        holder.companyName.setText(symbol.getCompanyName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return symbol_list.size();
    }

    class SymbolHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView symbol, companyName;
        public SymbolHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
            companyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Symbol Class**

```
public class Symbol {
    private String symbol;
    private String companyName;

    public Symbol(){

    }
    public Symbol(String symbol, String companyName){
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}
```

**Search Fragment**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

         recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.search_item_recylerView);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         list = new ArrayList<>();

        ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 Log.d("symbol", "executing? ");

                 if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                     for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                         Symbol s =ds.getValue(Symbol.class);
                         Log.d("symbol", s.getSymbol());
                         Log.d("symbol", s.getCompanyName());
                         list.add(s);
                     }
                     madapter= new SymbolAdapter(list);
                     recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });
        return view;
    }
```

When I run, the all logs that i put inside of addValueEventListener doesn't reach.
Is it because of Connection with firebase? I set to my database rule as true for read.
and I added 
    
to androidmanifest. 
However, it still doesn't work. and I checked connection with

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
        connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
                if (connected) {
                    Log.d("symbol", "connected");
                } else {
                    Log.d("symbol", "not connected");
                }
            }
```

Then addValueEventListener look reach to onDataChange but "not connected" is printed even if I added to manifest.

Thank you so much

Comment: chck if onCancelled is called? tyr put logs in onCancelled

Answer (score 0):

If the `not connected` is printed from your listener on `.info/connected` that means that your app is not connected to the Firebase Database server. Since that is the case, your other handlers won't be able to get any data from the server, and their `onDataChange` won't fire.

To solve this problem, you'll need to figure out why the Firebase client can't connect to the server. This is typically something either with the internet connection on your device/emulator, or something along the way between your client and the server blocking the traffic. If the reason isn't obvious from logcat output, consider [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) in the Firebase client to see its detailed output.

Comment: It seems that when I open android studio, it is connected then after few minutes later, it is disconnected

Comment: The Firebase client auto-closes the connection after a few minute or so **if** there is no active listener **and** there are no writes happening in that time. As long as there is an active listener or writes, the Firebase client won't close the connection. Android might, but I've only see it do that when the app is not actively being used.